# early-stopping changes final epoch in training each time

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, image-classification, regularization

I am training a CNN built using transfer learning with a VGG16 network as pre-trained model, and in the training I am using early-stopping as regularization technique. I have run several time the training, and what I see is that early stopping stops the training process everytime at a different epoch, so for example if I train the CNN the first time I arrive until the epoch 17, then another day I train again the network and during training it arrives at the epoch 8, and the epoch at which arrives it is different everytime.

Is this normal? I don't understand why everytime it changes the epoch at which it arrives.

Can someone explain this to me? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT] My code for the training is the following:

```
from keras import callbacks
# fit the transferNet on the training data
stopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=3)

steps_per_epoch = train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
val_steps = test_generator.n//test_generator.batch_size+1

try:
    history_transfer = transfer_model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
epochs=100, verbose=1, callbacks=[stopping],\
                    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,\
                    validation_data=test_generator,\
                    validation_steps=val_steps)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: Are you setting your seeds and all?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have edited my question with more details.

Comment: The extra info isn't useful, seeds are different thing, read about reproducibility issues in DL imo

Comment: Thanks, I have looked around and I think I should impose a seed. But can I ask you if the fact that the result is different each time will influence the quality of the prediction? Thanks.

Comment: Quality is vague. Without ensuring reproducability it will fluctuate. Now if you aks how much it will fluctuate practically small to moderatelly, in other words you cant expect to "optimise" random seeds to get perfect predictions from a bad architecture.